# how to hide the cursor in my GTK Application (written in C)

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

I'm trying to create a fullscreen application that will hide the cursor to display a video file. Currently, everything is working fine except the ability to hide the cursor (It's obnoxious having a cursor stuck over the video and makes for poor presentation).

My project is written in C, not C++, and is using the GTK+-3.0 library as well as WebKitGtk.
If anyone could be of assistance with hiding the cursor (I'd assume this is really simple, but maybe I'm undercutting it). Lastly, this is being ran and compiled on Ubuntu 12.04.

So is there a way to hide this annoying cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`gdk_window_set_cursor()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-cursor) with `GDK_BLANK_CURSOR`.